# How to change root of Umbraco site?

Tags: umbraco

I have a website and sub-pages where I develop sites. Example:

```
www.developersite.com/website1   
www.developersite.com/website2
```

I then have Umbraco set up for each of those pages. But when I go live to

```
www.website1.com
www.website2.com
```

I want to make sure that media links etc. point to the right place. My question is, can I set up, say, www.developersite.com/website1 as the root for website1? So that media files of the form

```
img src="/media/example.png"
```

work correctly and such?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have multiple sites hosted in Umbraco (and support for this is pretty good), I think you want to have the sites at the root. It sounds like you're adding some container to hold sub-sites higher up in the hierarchy.

you should have:

```
root
--www.website1.com
--www.website2.com
```

not:

```
root
--www.developersite.com
----www.website1.com
----www.website2.com
```

now `/media/1.jpg` when called from `website1.com/index.htm` will resolve to `website1.com/media/1.jpg`

Comment: It's not my choice, I'm working with what I'm given. Is there a way to tell umbraco to think that developersite is the root??

Comment: You should be able to use "manage hostnames" at the grandchild level (ie website1.com), to assign unique hostnames to each of the sites. Then "/media/1.jpg" would work. Make sure you also set ensureUniqueaming and useDomainPrefixes to true: (http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/3295-Need-some-help-managing-hostnames)